# Why I cannot embed Plotly graphy into a html file by javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, html

Here is my app.py contents:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request,jsonify
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static')
wsgi_app = app.wsgi_app

@app.route('/testTT')
def testTT():
    return render_template('testTT.html')


@app.route('/btdata',methods=['GET'])
def btdata():
    df = pd.read_csv('/home/qpf/data/backtest.csv')  
    df['b_yield'] = df['b_yield'] / 100 
    df['r_yield'] = df['r_yield'] / 100
    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace( go.Scatter(
        x=df['trade_date'],
        y=df['b_yield'],
        name='Benchmark',
        line_color='red',
        hovertemplate = 'Benchmark: %{y:.2%}<extra></extra>', 
    )
    )
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=df['trade_date'],
            y=df['r_yield'],
            mode='lines',
            fill='tozeroy',
            line_color='blue',
            name='Strategy',
            hovertemplate = 'Strategy: %{y:.2%}%<extra></extra>', 
        ) 
    )
    fig.update_layout( 
        title={
        'text':'Backtest Performance',
        'font':{
            'size':30,
            'color':'black'  
        },  
        'x':0.5
    },
        yaxis=dict(
        tickformat='2%',
        ),
        hovermode="x unified"  
    )
    div_plot = plotly.offline.plot(fig,include_plotlyjs=False, output_type='div')
    print(div_plot)
    return jsonify(div_plot)
```

then,I have a testTT.js file like these:

```
let htmlOutput;
const btimgFunc = () => {
  fetch('/btdata')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      const div_str  = data;
      htmlOutput.innerHTML += '<div class="backtest_img"> <script src="https://unpkg.com/plotly.js@1.58.4/dist/plotly.min.js"></script>';
      htmlOutput.innerHTML += div_str
      htmlOutput.innerHTML += '</div>';
      htmlOutput.scrollTop = htmlOutput.scrollHeight;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
};
const app = () => {
  htmlOutput = document.getElementById("htmlOutput");
};
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", app);
class BacktestShow extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    this.innerHTML = `
        <div class="html-output" id="htmlOutput">
          <div class="backtest-img">
          <h1>BackTest</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
  `
  btimgFunc()
  }
}
customElements.define("html-BacktestShow", BacktestShow);
```

the testTT.html like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Backtest Show</title>
  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='JS/testTT.js') }}"></script>
</head>
<body>
<html-BacktestShow></html-BacktestShow>
</body>
```

The problem, when I link to testTT.html, app.py runs correctly and the div*plot is passed to testTT.js in btimgFunc.  The div_str and  htmlOutput.innerHTML are also correct so that I copied the string of htmlOutput.innerHTML and pasted them into a html file, the file can correct shows the image.

However, the testTT.js/testTT.html cannot show the image indeed.

I don't know why. Anyone can help me? Thanks a lot.

I just want to realize the function:

user links to the http://my_url:5000/testTT, which can show the plotly image, and the image data from the bacttest.csv file which saved in the server.

How can I fix the problem?